# Run a macro automatically but not in ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to set a timer of 5 minutes on my userform. It works when I press the command button.

How do I make it run automatically at the start ? I tried in `ThisWorkbook` but it didn't worked.

here's the code :

In a module:

```
Public Const AllowedTime As Double = 1
```

In the Userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim userClickedPause As Boolean ' Gets set to True by the Pause button

Dim stopTime As Date

    userClickedPause = False
    ' If AllowedTime is the number of minutes with a decimal part:
    stopTime = DateAdd("s", Int(AllowedTime * 600), Now) ' add seconds to current time

    ' If AllowedTime is the number of seconds:
    'stopTime = DateAdd("s", AllowedTime, Now) ' add seconds to current time
    Do
        With UserForm1.TextBox1
            .Value = Format(stopTime - Now, "Nn:Ss")
        End With
        DoEvents
        If userClickedPause = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until Now >= stopTime


End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    userClickedPause = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `Timer` event?

Comment: there's none. @braX I also wont need the pause function of this code. I just wanna see 10 minutes go by.

Comment: Well that's why it's "not working" then.

Comment: @braX I dont know what and what part of the code to place in ThisWorkbook to have it run automatically. For now, I have to click on a command button to run 10 minutes to 0. I would like to have it run once I open the workbook. This is what I dont know how. I pasted the code `CommandButton1_Click()` in `ThisWorkbook` but nothings happening.

Comment: Did you put it in the right event? or did you just paste it in randomly with no specific name? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to re-structure your code. Since you want to call your StartTimer sub from both a `UserForm` and the `Workbook_Open` event, put it into a module.

Then you simply call the sub from your `Commandbutton1_Click` event and the `Workbook_Open` event.

```
'Put this code inside ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'This sub into ThisWorkbook
    Application.Run "SetTimer"
End Sub

'This sub goes into a module
Private Sub SetTimer()
    'Here goes your code that sets the timer
    '(move it from your UserForm)
    '.......................................
    '.......................................
End Sub

'The code inside your UserForm
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Run "SetTimer"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Codingnoob Check if "Events" are enabled. You can type `?Application.EnableEvents` into the "Immediate Window" inside the VBE. If it returns `FALSE`, you can type `Application.EnableEvents=True` to enable events.

Comment: Well, if you have your code inside `ThisWorkbook` in the `Workbook_Open()` Sub and Events enables, the only further thing that comes into my mind would be security settings that prevent the macro from running when the workbook opens. But I assume you checked those?

Comment: Have you tried it? It doenst work at all. Also you ommited to tell me where do I insert `Public Const AllowedTime As Double = 1`. I copied it inside another module, it still only works when I click the command button. It doesn't run automatically.

Comment: The Public declaration can be in any module (but not in the UserForm, Sheet or ThisWorkbook). And no, I have not tried it, I showed you the general approach - which works if done right.

Comment: Ok! It worked on my userform. I dont have to run the command anymore... but the excel sheets wont load. Excel is trying to open but it's stuck at '100%'.

Comment: it's actually the `Public Const AllowedTime As Double = 1` that is not letting my excel fully open. Any tips? Btw I accepted your answer.

Comment: What do mean with "not letting my Excel fully open".  If Excel - for any reason - does not start completely, it won't trigger the Workbook_Open event either.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wwsqVAl that's what I mean. The UserForm opens, and everything runs smoothly, but i can't see the WorkSheets! It's stuck at 100%.

Comment: So it's stuck at 100% and nothing happens? Do you need to force stop Excel in the task manager? Does it only happen with this particular workbook? If not, you might check [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-file-wont-open-stuck-on-100/735c2ea6-e005-48c5-9bcf-777e6a5e417a). Otherwise, I cannot really tell what the problem is from your  code, unfortunately.

Comment: It is caused by the macro that starts running as soon as we open the excel file. The macro keeps running as long as the timer is on, and As soon as the timer hits 0, The Excel Sheets finally opens up.

Comment: Ok, but that means the Workbook_Open event works fine. Then you just need to change your code.

Comment: As far as I see it, before you call the `SetTimer` Sub from the `Workbook_Open` event, you will need to open the UserForm (modeless!), like `UserForm1.Show Modeless`. Put that one first into the `Workbook_Open()` event. Because now, you run the timer but the UserForm is never even opened.

Comment: yes thats what I already have. The userform shows but not the sheets.. well it's fine i guess, it's not that important to see the sheets!

Comment: Good to hear. Not sure if that can be fixed anyway. Probably the same problem like Excel blanking out while a heavy macro is running.